# AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'show_frame' in tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-entry

This is the full traceback message

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__ return self.func(*args) File "C:\test.py", line 61, in <lambda> canvas.tag_bind(obj1, '<1>', lambda event=None : controller.show_frame(Page1)) AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'show_frame
```

**WHAT I WANT ?**

When I should click on the image, it should redirect to another frame that is Page1.

**WHAT I AM GETTING ?**

when I click on the image in order to move on the Page1 (next frame) from the StartPage (default frame), it is showing error "AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'show_frame'"

Following is my code that is giving error.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
   
class tkinterApp(Tk): 
      
    # __init__ function for class tkinterApp  
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):  
          
        # __init__ function for class Tk 
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs) 
          
        # creating a container 
        container = Frame(self)   
        container.pack(side = "top", fill = "both", expand = True)  
   
        # initializing frames to an empty array 
        self.frames = {}
        
        # iterating through a tuple consisting 
        # of the different page layouts 
        for F in (StartPage, Page1): 
   
            frame = F(container, self) 
   
            # initializing frame of that object from 
            # startpage, page1, page2 respectively with  
            # for loop 
            self.frames[F] = frame  
   
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky ="nsew")
        self.update()
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
   
    # to display the current frame passed as 
    # parameter 
    def show_frame(self, cont): # cont = page_name
        if cont not in self.frames:
            self.frames[cont] = cont(container, self)
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.event_generate("<<ShowFrame>>")
   
# first window frame startpage 
   
class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.myStartPage)

    def printcehck(self,event):
        print("hack")

    def myStartPage(self,controller):
        super(StartPage).__init__()
        print(controller)
        canvas = Canvas(self,width=300, height=300, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        canvas.pack()

        self.background = PhotoImage(file="background.png")
        canvas.create_image(300,300,image=self.background, tags="B")

        self.character1 = PhotoImage(file="bg-e-butd.png")
        obj1 = canvas.create_image(50,50,image=self.character1, anchor=NW)
        canvas.tag_bind(obj1, '<1>', lambda event=None : controller.show_frame(self,Page1)) #error occurs here.
           
      
# second window frame page1  
class Page1(Frame): 
      
    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
          
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        canvas = Canvas(self,width=300, height=300, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, relief='ridge')
        canvas.pack()

        self.background = PhotoImage(file="background.png")
        canvas.create_image(300,300,image=self.background, tags="B")

        self.character1 = PhotoImage(file="bg-e-butd.png")
        self.after(1000, lambda: (canvas.create_image(50,50,image=self.character1, anchor=NW)))

   
# Driver Code 
app = tkinterApp()
app.title("Title")
app.mainloop()
```

Can anyone let me know where I'm doing the mistake ? I'm new in GUI development using Tkinter.

Comment: 2 problems I see. You are missing the `self.` prefix in a couple places and you are passing `self` to `show_frame` when you do not need to because that is passed automatically within tkinter methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define controller as a class attribute. The error is telling you that `show_frame` does not exist because to that attribute `controller` does not exist.

In order to pass your frame to the other class properly you need to also define container as a class attribute in the main class.

Change `container` to `self.container`

In your `StartPage` class and `Page1` class you will need to add `self.controller = controller` to your **init** so that the rest of your class will be able to work with this.

I have updated your code (also removed the image portions as I dont have your images to work with) so I used some labels instead.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class tkinterApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.title("Title")
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, Page1):
            frame = F(self.container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.update()
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):  # cont = page_name
        if cont not in self.frames:
            self.frames[cont] = cont(self.container, self)
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.event_generate("<<ShowFrame>>")


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text='StartPage').pack()
        self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.myStartPage)
        self.controller = controller

    def printcehck(self, event):
        print("hack")

    def myStartPage(self, controller):
        super(StartPage).__init__()
        print(controller)
        self.controller.show_frame(Page1)


class Page1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        tk.Label(self, text='Page1').pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tkinterApp().mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! using `self.controller = controller` resolved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of the event callback (2nd for class method) is the `Event` object, so when the class method below is used as the event callback:

```
def myStartPage(self, controller):
```

`controller` will be the `Event` object. This is the cause of the exception when you use it in:

```
canvas.tag_bind(obj1, '<1>', lambda event=None : controller.show_frame(self,Page1)) #error occurs here.
```

To fix the issue, you need to change to following line:

```
self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", self.myStartPage)
```

to:

```
self.bind("<<ShowFrame>>", lambda e: self.myStartPage(controller))
```

---

Note that you have to remove the extra argument `self` in the following line as well:

```
canvas.tag_bind(obj1, '<1>', lambda event=None : controller.show_frame(self,Page1))
```

That is:

```
canvas.tag_bind(obj1, '<1>', lambda event=None : controller.show_frame(Page1))
```

---

Also the following line inside `myStartPage()` is not necessary:

```
super(StartPage).__init__()
```